# Converting latitude/longitude to Alberta 10 TM Projection

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, proj4js, proj

I need to convert latitude/longitude coordinates into Easting/Northing coordinates in the Alberta 10 TM Projection.

The 10 TM projection is similar to UTM, but it is a custom projection for the province of Alberta, Canada.  I think (with some effort) I could code it myself but would rather not reinvent the wheel if it's been done already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grab [PROJ Cartographic Projections library](https://proj.org) - open source library.

Suggested parameters for 10TM:

> +proj=tmerc +lon_0=-115 +k_0=0.9992 +x_0=500000 +datum=NAD27

According to [this post](http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/data2/wilma/mapserver-users/0311/msg00336.html) you may need to:

> change the ellps to GRS80 if your 10TM
> data is referenced to the NAD83 datum
> (instead of NAD27/clrk66).  You may
> also need to change the false northing
> (y_0) to be -5000000 if your 10TM
> coordinates for Alberta are less than
> 5,000,000 (an AltaLIS "standard").

I should mention that proj.4 is *the library* to get for any kind of geographic coordinate system transformation.  There's pretty much no transformation it can't do.

I also recommend reading [Map Projections-A Working Manual (Paperback) by John Snyder](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395) if you are into these kinds of things.. it's a classic. :) (fixed the link)

Answer (score 4):

I've used GDAL (http://www.gdal.org) to do this. It supports bindings for many different languages as well.

Comment: Isn't that only for rasters? Not clear whether the question is about rasters.

Comment: gdal provides support for rasters and vector (OGR). It also provides spatial references (OSR) that can do coordinate conversions.

Answer (score 2):

For free GIS libraries, take a look here: http://www.freegis.org/database/?cat=12. Hopefully you can find something that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously consider using a third party dll to do this rather than code it yourself.

I don't know the full details of the 10 TM projection, but I worked on a project that required coordinate conversions between many different coordinate systems to a high degree of accuracy, including UTM and Lat/Long. We found that the maths involved was way too complicated.

Perhaps take a look at the open source PROJ.4:
http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

They seems to support a huge range of conversions, and so I hope Alberta 10 TM will be covered.

Answer (score 1):

Download the opensource GIS application `MapWindow`

Open the GIS Tools menu

And use their shapefile reprojection tool. Under "National Grids Canada" you can select this Alberta projection.

-Jeff Tiemann
jefftiemann@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://code.google.com/p/android-openmap-framework/ which can convert an Android Location to a LatLonPoint, UTMPoint, or MGRSPoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your coordinates pairs to [Coordinate System Transformation - online service](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu) where you can set appropriate input and desired output coordinate system. There are hundreds of coordinate systems - it is possible to simply find appropriate coordinate system using any keyword. You can see **editable proj4 text definition** for each coordinate system so if you need to modify any projection parametr, you can do it there. Or **you can define your own custom projection**...