# UTM and MGRS to Latitude/Longitude conversion source-code?

Tags: open-source, latitude-longitude, utm

What open-source / public domain software is there "out there" for conversion between Latitude/Longitude, UTM (Universal Transform Mercator) and MGRS (Military Grid Reference System)? We're using a VB6 library at the moment and would prefer to use something in another language and with a longer pedigree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937/converting-latitudelongitude-to-alberta-10-tm-projection) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176137/java-convert-latlon-to-utm).

Answer (score 2):

[PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/); I don't know if it does MGRS, but I seem to recall that it did Lat/Lon -> UTM when I last used it.